# Can I import homebrewed alcohol to Norway?

Tags: legal, customs-and-immigration, alcohol, norway

In Norway, as far as I know, the sale of all alcohol is nationalized. I'm going to visit my friend there, and his parents want to send him a bottle (He is from Slovakia, same as myself). Is it legal to bring home-brewed alcohol with me to Norway?

Comment: It's hard to tell if alcohol is home-brewed or not. You can always buy alcohol and put it in an undifferentiated bottle to look home brewed or the other way around. I doubt they make a distinction. Plus, afaik, the spirit of the law is to control alchool sale, not alchool sale brewed by the industry.

Comment: I would check not just the legality of importing to Norway, but also the legality of exporting from Slovakia.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The import laws cited on the [the page of Norway's Toll Office](http://toll.no/templates_TAD/Article.aspx?id=195294&epslanguage=en) do not distinguish between the manner the alcohol has been created (because that would likely be rather difficult); only by the strength. You're allowed for free (see the link for how much you have to pay if you need to import larger quantities):

- One litre of an alcoholic beverage containing more than 22% and up to 60% alcohol by volume and one and a half litres containing more than 2.5% up to 22% alcohol by volume, or three litres of beverages containing more than 2.5% and up to 22% alcohol by volume
- Two litres of beer containing more than 2.5% alcohol by volume, or other beverage containing more than 2.5% and up to 4.7% alcohol by volume. This means, for example, that you can import five litres of beer if you do not have other alcoholic beverages with you

Note that you need to be over 18 to import alcohol at all, and over 20 to import hard (>22%) liquor.

The same information in pictures:
[image]

Comment: These are the duty-free limits.  It should be perfectly legal to bring in more than these amounts, but you'll have to declare it and pay the duties (which are listed on the linked page, and appear to be very high).

Comment: @NateEldredge: oh, good point. I'll clarify that.

Comment: WTF? It's prohibited to import potatoes :D

Comment: @JaroslavBucko: Agricultural pests and diseases aren't the same everywhere on the planet. Farmers would really like to avoid them being accidentally imported, so that they don't have to protect their crops against yet another menace. That's why it's forbidden to import fruits, vegetables, and plants in many places.